# Ajax requests time in Laravel 5

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I have a question regarding the ajax requests time with Laravel 5. I have the below code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    url: "/test.php",
    data: '_token=' + $("#_token").val() + '&idfoselection=' + id,
    success: function(r){}
});
```

the request time is **1ms-2ms**. test.php is an empty file in public folder

If I change the ajax url with a route, (url: "/test-ajax") and inside routes.php I have:

```
Route::post('test-ajax', ['as' => 'test-ajax', function() {
    die;
}]);
```

the request time is very big, **86ms-100ms**.

Is there any way how can I improve this time using Laravel 5? I tried with APC or php artisan optimise...there is a small improvement but is not enough for me.

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you want on your page that requires a result in < 86ms?

Comment: I'm trying to discover why using Laravel routes, the requests time is very big. I have over ~400 requests / seconds on my production environment and this loading time is very big comparing with the framework that I used in the past. Comparing 1ms vs 80-100ms is a lot imo.

Comment: What are you to trying to __do__ / __accomplish__? You still haven't explained that. For example we have a customer who has a bid website that does an ajax call for every item on the frontpage and who expected 50k visitors simultaneously.. Other technologies and implementations provided a solution to that question. So what are you trying to do? Higher load times due to using a framework can be expected.

Comment: Higher load times due to using a framework can be expected. - my sentiments exactly!